# predict.coxph() and survC1::Est.Cval -- type for predict() output

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Given a `coxph()` model, I want to use `predict()` to predict hazards and then use `survC1::Est.Cval( . . . nofit=TRUE)` to get a c-value for the model.

The `Est.Cval()` documentation is rather terse, but says that *"nofit=TRUE: If TRUE, the 3rd column of mydata is used as the risk score directly in calculation of C."*

Say, for simplicity, that I want to predict on the same data I built the model on. For

- `coxModel` a Cox regression model from `coxph()`;
- `time` a vector of times (positive reals), the same times that `coxModel` was built on; and
- `event` a 0/1 vector, the same length, of event/censor indicators, the same events that `coxModel` was built on --

does this indicate that I want

```
predictions <- predict(coxModel, type="risk")

dd <- cbind(time, event, pred)

Est.Cval(mydata=dd, tau=tau, nofit=TRUE)
```

or should that first line be

```
predictions <- predict(coxModel, type="lp")
```

?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: I'm guessing this line would fail: `dd <- cbind(time, event, pred)` with an error unless you `attach`-ed some dataframe that you are not telling us about. This question is far from being a [MCVE]

Comment: @42: `time` is a vector of times (postive reals), `event` is a 0/1 vector of the same length, I should have put that in the question.I didn't ask with a complete MWE because it's not that the code doesn't run -- it's that I'm not sure what value is needed for a certain argument (the function will run with the wrong value), I'm not certain from the doc, and I'm hoping that someone more familiar with the package is sure. I thought it might distract from the question to also add actual survival data?

Comment: I don’t think adding data and reproducible code EVER detracts from a question. Especially when a question involves a seldom used package such as survC1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that ***it doesn't matter***.

Basically, the concordance value is testing, for all comparable pairs of times (events and censors), how probable it is that the later time has the lower risk (for a really good model, almost always). But since e^u is a monotonic function of real u, and the c-value is only testing comparisons, it doesn't matter whether you provide the hazard ratio, e^(sum{\beta_i x_i}), or the linear predictor, sum{\beta_i x_i}.

Since @42 motivated me to come up with a minimal working example, we can test this. We'll compare the values that `Est.Cval()` provides using one input versus using the other; and we can compare both to the value we get from `coxph()`.

(That last value won't match exactly, because `Est.Cval()` uses the method of Uno et al. 2011 *(Uno, H., Cai, T., Pencina, M. J., D’Agostino, R. B. & Wei, L. J. On the C-statistics for evaluating overall adequacy of risk prediction procedures with censored survival data. Statist. Med. 30, 1105–1117 (2011), https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.4154)* but it can serve as a sanity check, since the values should be close.)

The following is based on the example worked through in *Survival Analysis with R*, 2017-09-25, by Joseph Rickert, https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/.

```
library("survival")
library("survC1")

# Load dataset included with survival package
data("veteran")
# The variable `time` records survival time; `status` indicates whether the 
# patient’s death was observed (status=1) or that survival time was censored 
# (status = 0). 

# The model they build in the example:
coxModel <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + celltype + karno + diagtime + 
    age + prior, data=veteran)

# The results
summary(coxModel)
```

Note the c-score it gives us:

```
Concordance= 0.736  (se = 0.021 )
```

Now, we calculate the c-score given by `Est.Cval()` on the two types of values:

```
# The value from Est.Cval(), using a risk input
cvalByRisk <- Est.Cval(mydata=cbind(time=veteran$time, event=veteran$status, 
  predictions=predict(object=coxModel, newdata=veteran, type="risk")), 
  tau=2000, nofit=TRUE)

# The value from Est.Cval(), using a linear predictor input
cvalByLp <- Est.Cval(mydata=cbind(time=veteran$time, event=veteran$status, 
  predictions=predict(object=coxModel, newdata=veteran, type="lp")), 
  tau=2000, nofit=TRUE)
```

And we compare the results:

```
cvalByRisk$Dhat
[1] 0.7282348
cvalByLp$Dhat
[1] 0.7282348
```